# What's the meaning of "The Pole is wise when the damage is done"

Tags: proverbs

I came across this line while reading the Novel Kane and Abel by Jeffrey Archer.

In the novel, Abel uses this line when he sees his hotel burned to the ground.

I searched a lot but found just one [link](http://ampoleagle.com/proverbs-sayings-mottos-and-notions-p6125-96.htm) in which explanation is given as follows , which is still not clear to me :-

> Madry Polak po szkodzie
>
> Equivalent: Lock the stable after the horse has bolted.
>
> Literally: A Pole is wise after the damage has been done.

Any explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: Never heard this phrase before, but it would appear very self-explanatory to me. What do *you* think it could possibly mean? Please list all the different meanings that you have in mind. I can list only one.

Comment: Twain said something like "A man who carries a cat by the tail learns something he can learn in no other way."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's either about a non-standard gloss, or lacking reasonable research (and probably qa duplicate).

Comment: The remark appears to be an ethnic slur against Polish people, suggesting they can only be wise after an event (that they lack foresight). "Pole" with a capital P is an old-fashioned British term meaning "Polish person".

Comment: There's a similar one in welsh (*Paid â chodi pais ar ôl piso*) which has the *don't cry over spilt milk*/*locking the stable door after the horse has bolted* meaning. It literally means *Don't lift your petticoat after you have wee'd*. They don't all make sense in current day parlance - who wears petticoats anymore? (or wee's in public) - but are used as a phrase for a concept.

Comment: Wee's -- who adds apostrophes to verbs in public?

Comment: It is possibly worth noting that Jeffrey Archer is a convicted criminal who served a prison sentence for perjury, and is not regarded as a good writer.

Comment: Abel not Able.  https://www.amazon.com/Kane-Abel-Jeffrey-Archer-ebook/dp/B003JMF4FC

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear whether the OP is referring to a rod (*per* title) or an ethnic group (*per* question body).

Comment: Whether it's a "slur" or not, "Pole" refers to someone of Polish heritage.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey He didn't serve time for crimes against literature, but many people think that he should've done :-)

Comment: @puppetsock , corrected the spelling. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Locking the stable (or barn door) after the horse has bolted is a common English idiom for fixing a problem when it's too late -- the damage has already been done.

The Polish version states it more simply: people only learn (become wise) after they made a mistake.

If this were being said by non-Polish people, the reference to Poles might be an ethnic slur (in less enlightened times it was common in America to use Poles as the butt of jokes). But since this is actually a Polish proverb, and the character is Polish, I believe it's just using "A Pole" to refer to people in general.

Comment: The OP provided a link to a Polish proverb to the effect of the item. I think it's at least vaguely possible that, rather than an ethnic slur, it's a direct copy of a Polish proverb. Considering that the Abel in the title of the book is Polish.

Comment: Ah, I didn't understand the context. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Why answer when the opening comment asks the poster to try to figure it out themselves? It seems to be obvious, as you acknowledge in posting without supporting evidence.

Comment: @Xanne When I first answered, I thought it was related to Polish jokes, which the OP would probably not know about. I've since realized that was wrong, but I already had an answer, so I revised it.

Comment: @puppetsock  Yes, Abel in the title of the book is Polish.

Comment: @Barmar , Your answer does makes sense.

Comment: It was written on a statue in one the world's largest castles, Malbork castle in Pomerania Poland.